# How can I get this currying experiment to behave as expected?

Tags: haskell, currying

I am writing a currying experiment to get a feel for how multiple statements in haskell are chained together to work one after another.

Here is what I got so far

```
testCurry :: IO ()
testCurry =     
    (\b ->
        (\_ -> putStrLn b)
        ((\a -> 
            putStrLn a
        ) (show 2))
    ) (show 3)

testCurryExpected :: IO ()
testCurryExpected = do {
    a <- return (show 2);
    putStrLn a;
    b <- return (show 3);
    putStrLn b;
}

main :: IO ()
main = 
    putStrLn "expected: " >>
    testCurryExpected >>
    putStrLn "given: " >>
    testCurry
```

I know it works if I do it this way:

```
testCurry :: IO ()
testCurry =     
    (\b ->
        (\next -> next >> putStrLn b)
        ((\a -> 
            putStrLn a
        ) (show 2))
    ) (show 3)

testCurryExpected :: IO ()
testCurryExpected = do {
    a <- return (show 2);
    putStrLn a;
    b <- return (show 3);
    putStrLn b;
}

main :: IO ()
main = 
    putStrLn "expected: " >>
    testCurryExpected >>
    putStrLn "given: " >>
    testCurry
```

But I don't know how to simulate the ">>"(then) behavior only using functions.

I know `a >> b` is defined in terms of `a >>= \_ -> b`, but I am not sure how `>>=` is defined in terms of `IO a >>= IO b` but don't know how to translate this into raw function composition.

Can somebody please help me get this experiment to work?

In short, I want to know if there is a way to do this without >> or >>= operators nor wrapping these operators.

```
(\a -> \b -> a >> b)(putStrLn "one")(putStrLn "two")
```

Note: For the sake of concept, I restrict myself to using anonymous functions of at most one argument.

Edit: I found a good-enough solution by creating my own Free representation of putStrLn called Free_PutStrLn that is free of interpretation; using Lists to construct the operation chain, then evaluate it myself later.

```
data Free_PutStrLn = Free_PutStrLn String deriving Show

eval :: [Free_PutStrLn] -> IO ()
eval a = 
    foldl (\a -> \b -> 
        let deconstruct (Free_PutStrLn str) = str in
        a >> putStrLn (deconstruct b)
    ) (return ()) a

testCurry :: [Free_PutStrLn]
testCurry = 
    (\a ->
        [Free_PutStrLn a] ++
        ((\b ->
            [Free_PutStrLn b]
        ) (show 3))
    )(show 2)

main = 
    putStrLn (show testCurry) >>
    eval (testCurry)
```

JavaScript proof of concept:

```
// | suspends an object within a function context.
// | first argument is the object to suspend.
// | second argument is the function object into which to feed the suspended
// |     argument(first).
// | third argument is where to feed the result of the first argument feeded into 
// |     second argument. use a => a as identity.
const pure = obj => fn => f => f(fn(obj));

// | the experiment
pure({'console': {
    'log': str => new function log() {
        this.str = str;
    }
}})(free =>
    pure(str => () => console.log(str))
    (putStrLn => 
        pure("hello")(a => 
            [free.console.log(a)].concat (
            pure("world")(b => 
                [free.console.log(b)]
            )(a => a))
        )((result => 
            pure(logObj => logObj.str)
            (deconstruct => 
                result.map(str => putStrLn(deconstruct(str)))
            )(result =>
                result.forEach(f => f())
            )        
        )
    )
    )(a => a)
)(a => a)
```

Comment: I don't think this question has anything to do with currying; are you confusing "currying" with the desugaring of `do`-notation, maybe?

Comment: the do notation desugars into the monadic form, this is a bit deeper in that I want to know whether it is possible to turn the desugared version into a explicit functional expression for performing such a chaining. It appears that it is impossible to bypass the need for >>= or >> but it is definitely possible to decouple the need for >>= and >> from the explicit functional version, and then evaluate that free of interpretation version independently.

Comment: I am still unconvinced that it is completely impossible to replace >> and >>= with some clever currying, but it seems impossible without resorting to building up a listlike object and folding over it before returning.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at [IOSpec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/IOSpec), a pure implementation of the IO monad.

Answer (score 3):

> But I don't know how to simulate the `>>` (then) behavior only using functions.

Well, you can't! `>>` is (in this case) about ordering side-effects. A Haskell function can never have a side effect<sup>†</sup>. Side effects can only happen in monadic actions, and can be thus ordered by monadic combinators including [`>>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-Instances.html#v:-62--62-), but without a `Monad`<sup>‡</sup> constraint the notion of “do this and also that” simply doesn't make any sense in Haskell. A Haskell function is not *executed*, it's merely a mathematical transformation whose result you may *evaluate*. That result may itself be an actual *action* with type e.g. `IO ()`, and such an *action* can be executed and/or monadically chained with other actions. But this is actually somewhat orthogonal to the evaluation of the function that yielded this action.

So that's the answer: “How can I get this currying experiment to behave as expected?” You can't, you need to use one of the monadic combinators instead (or `do` notation, which is just syntactic sugar for the same).

---

To also tackle this question from a bit of a different angle: you do *not* “need monads” to express sequencing of side effects. I might for instance define a type that “specifies side-effects” by generating e.g. Python code which when executed has these effects:

```
newtype Effect = Effect { pythons :: [String] }
```

Here, you could then sequence effects by simply concatenating the instruction lists. Again though, this sequencing would not be accomplished by any kind of currying exercise but by boring list concatenation. The preferable interface for this is the [monoid class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html):

```
import Data.Monoid
instance Monoid Effect where
  mempty = Effect []
  mappend (Effect e₀) (Effect e₁) = Effect $ e₀ ++ e₁
```

And then you could simply do:

```
hello :: Effect
hello = Effect ["print('hello')"] <> Effect ["print('world')"]
```

(`<>` is just a shorthand synonym for `mappend`. You could as well define a custom operator, say `#` instead to chain those actions, but if there's a standard class that supports some operation it's usually a good idea to employ that!)

Ok, perfectly fine sequencing, no monadic operators required.

But very clearly, just *evaluating* `hello` would not cause anything to be printed: it would merely give you some other source code. You'd actually need to feed these instructions to a Python interpreter to accomplish the side-effects.
And in principle that's no different with the `IO` type: evaluating an `IO` action also never causes any side-effects, only linking it to main (or to the GHCi repl) does. How many lambdas you wrap the subexpressions in is completely irrelevant for this, because side-effect occurance has *nothing* to do with whether a function gets called anywhere! It only has to do with how the actions get linked to an actual “executor”, be that a Python interpreter or Haskell's own `main`.

If you now wonder why it has to be those whacky monads if the simpler `Monoid` also does the trick... the problem with `Effect` is that it has no such thing as a return value. You can perfectly well generate “pure output” actions this way that simply execute a predetermined Python program, but you can never *get back* any values from Python this way to use within Haskell to decide what should happen next. This is what monads allow you to do.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Yes, *never*. Haskell *does **not** include* something called [`unsafePerformIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v:unsafePerformIO). Anybody who claims otherwise in the comments shall [suffer nuclear retaliation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/acme-missiles-0.3/docs/Acme-Missiles.html#v:launchMissiles).</sub>

<sup>‡</sup><sub>To be precise, [the weaker `Applicative` is sufficient](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-42--62-).</sub>

Comment: I think its possible if putStrLn and IO is replaced with a free monad representing putStrLn operation. This way the result of testCurry produces a list of actions that can be mapped into IO space and reduced/folded using >> operator.

Comment: @Dmitry Sure, if you use a "pure" IO definition you can do that. But you will not get actual outputs unless you use the standard IO and something like `>>` to sequence effects. This can be done, as you mention, with a fold with `>>`.

Comment: I posted a good enough solution based on that; i don't care about side effects, I just want to know how to represent operation chaining via composition so I can then use it as a proof of concept for a similar JavaScript experiment in which I want to represent everything in terms of functions of single arguments, without any semicolons nor automatic semicolon insertion that happens even if you don't put semicolons. But this has nothing to do with side effects, but rather it has to do with "operation chaining"; IO monad is the only monad that lets you see what's going on in the middle-

Comment: The only other way to inspect whats going on in the middle of a monad(IO monad cheats by having side effects) is to create a freeish monad(not necessarily a full blown Free Monad™) and then map sequences of such objects to the second order functions representing the real functions, and then reduce these functions.

Comment: I was curious about keeping it in IO but never using >>= nor >> but instead cleverly currying the actions around. But I am convinced that even though IO () is empty, it works by folding over the implicit sequence of actions before returning, collapsing them into a unit tuple. So I can't just throw away each next expression without silencing them. In all cases, I must either snowball the expressions and reduce over them otherwise only one statement gets evaluated.

Comment: I think the closest I can get to is `test = foldl (\a -> \b -> a >> b) (return ()) ([putStrLn "hello"] ++ [putStrLn "world"])` but theres no way to collapse 2 IO actions into a single io action without >> or >>=, even unsafePerformIO doesnt work since the compiler knows that the second argument is just going to get ignored so it never reaches to the unsafePerformIO statement.  eg `test = foldl (\a -> \b -> (const b) (Unsafe.unsafePerformIO a))(return ()) ([putStrLn "hello"] ++ [putStrLn "world"])`  only shows the last statement which is world.

Comment: Basically in haskell, even unsafePerformIO is lazy, and the only way to chain a and b monads together without ending up not evaluating them is to use `>>` or `>>=` both of which perform evaluation and compose a new object, or in IO case, only perform evaluation and create an empty tuple, but it evaluates in a way that even unsafePerformIO seems to not be able to(`(\_ -> putStrLn "hello") (unsafePerformIO (putStrLn "world"))` will only print hello, the argument is thrown out together with unsafePerformIO even if it was given a name.)

Comment: actually it doesn't even work if I do `(\a -> (return a) >> putStrLn "hi") (unsafePerformIO (putStrLn "something"))`. I imagine it sees that the argument is of type empty tuple and treats it as return () without evaluating it. Even if i try being clever with function calls it doesnt work O.o. `(\f -> (return (f "hello")))(\a -> unsafePerformIO (putStrLn a))` Im confused.

Comment: Correct analysis. As I already alluded, `unsafePerformIO` is not relevant at all here. Indeed that function is _not_ part of Haskell but of the _foreign function interface_, namely for calling C functions (and possibly memory allocations etc. around them); those could after all have side-effects and thus not correspond to Haskell functions. The sole purpose of `unsafePerformIO` is to _retrieve the results of such functions_ without a monadic bind, under the assumption that there is no observable side-effect. But if you use that for actions which do have side-effects, the result is undefined.

Comment: That said: you _can_ in fact trick GHC into sequencing the side-effects of “pure” values, by [forcing evaluation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:seq): ``(\a -> a `seq` putStrLn "hello") (unsafePerformIO (putStrLn "world"))`` prints first “world”, then “hello”. Incidentally, you don't need any of those lambdas to achieve that, ``unsafePerformIO (putStrLn "world") `seq` putStrLn "hello"`` does the same thing. But by no means rely on that kind of behaviour: the compiler may actually optimise this in a way that completely screws up the order etc.!

Comment: Nevertheless, if your question is really whether you specifically need the `Monad` class to sequence actions in general then the answer is _no_. That's just very much the natural interface for doing it, but you could also have a type without such an instance which nevertheless describes a sequence of side-effectful actions. I'll expand my answer...